# PHP Regex That Excludes WordPress Scaled Images

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

Using PHP 7.1, I need a regex pattern that will exclude all the scaled images from the old WordPress installation.  Unfortunately, some of the full size images have a similar nomenclature.  I'm needing preg_grep for this function.

Sample image array:

```
[0]=>
string(70) "/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/filename3-1-100x100.png"
[1]=>
string(78) "/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/filename-1-150x150-100x100.png"
[2]=>
string(62) "/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/filename-1.png"
[3]=>
string(68) "/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/filename-100x100.png"
[4]=>
string(76) "/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/filename-150x150-100x100.png"
[5]=>
string(60) "/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/filename.png"
```

The results I need:

```
/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/filename-1.png
/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/filename.png
```

I've tried negative look aheads:

```
.*(-\d{1})?(?![-\d{3}x\d{3}]?\.(jpg|png|bmp|gif|ico)
```

I've tried negative look behinds:

```
.*(?<![-\d{3}x\d{3}]\.(jpg|png|bmp|gif|ico))
```

I've tried negating the unwanted string:

```
.*(-\d)?[^-\d{3}x\d{3}]\.(jpg|png|bmp|gif|ico)
```

Under normal circumstances, I would use a plugin to rebuild the images for the new WordPress instance, however, this client has well over 10,000 images, and many of them are not attached to their WordPress posts.  The images exist for their social networks only.  I have to maintain all the old images so any incoming links are not broken, but I also need to rebuild the post images.  Unfortunately, when exporting a WordPress website, only the images attached to a post are included in the WXR rss export file.  This can leave thousands of images unaccounted, and requiring they be added manually using a plugin.

Comment: The culprit is `(?![-\d{3}x\d{3}]?`. Change your whole regex to `^(?!.*-\d{3}x\d{3})`

Comment: Thanks @revo. This does help, but this grabs all files and not just the designated image files.

Comment: Isn't this your expected output? https://3v4l.org/jhBEc

Comment: You are getting the correct output, but any php glob will grab all file types.  So I need just the image file types.

Comment: So you may want to add your own filter on it? `^(?!.*-\d{3}x\d{3}).*\.(jpg|png|bmp|gif|ico)$` https://regex101.com/r/u7TMTS/1

Comment: Bingo!  That did it!  Thank you.  Make this an answer, and I'll check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some mistakes in regex you made like confusing brackets usage with parentheses. Brackets will define a character class while parentheses intend to group a pattern. Otherwise you may have come to a working solution as this:

```
^(?!.*-\d{3}x\d{3}).*\.(jpg|png|bmp|gif|ico)$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/u7TMTS/1)

PHP code:

```
print_r(preg_grep("~^(?!.*-\d{3}x\d{3}).*\.(jpg|png|bmp|gif|ico)$~", $array));
```

Comment: Thank you @revo. I did modify this slightly to accommodate a few more image sizes.  I adjusted like this:
    `^(?!.*-\d{3,4}x\d{2,4}).*\.(jpg|png|bmp|gif|ico|pdf)$`
I also added pdf to the filter and that worked great as well. Very well done!